# Apache Beam Update side input from database

Tags: apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline that processes unbounded data and the results are written into MySQL. In this process, there is a need to look up the username from the user identifier. I'm using side input user id and username map to the pipeline.

Since we keep adding users, the side input needs to be updated periodically. I've gone through the side input patterns "Slowly updating global window side inputs" and "Slowly updating side input using windowing".

I lean towards the first due to new users added not being that frequent.

Reading users from the database using JdbcIO.

```
   final PCollection userCollection =
       pipeline.apply("read-users-info", jdbcMgr.readUserInfo(userDsFn));
```

Reading data from MySQL

```
  public PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KV<String, String>>> readUserInfo(
      SerializableFunction<Void, DataSource> dataSourceProviderFn) {
    LOG.info("reading users");
    return JdbcIO.<KV<String, String>>read()
        .withDataSourceProviderFn(dataSourceProviderFn)
        .withQuery("select id, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) from users")
        .withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
        .withRowMapper(
            (JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, String>>) rs -> KV.of(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
  }
}
```

Updating side input using global window.

```
    final PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> userMap =
        pipeline
            .apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(30)))
            .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30))))
            .apply(Sum.longsGlobally().withoutDefaults())
            .apply(
                ParDo.of(
                    new DoFn<Long, Map<String, String>>() {
                      @ProcessElement
                      public void process(
                          @Element Long input,
                          @Timestamp Instant timestamp,
                          OutputReceiver<PCollection<KV<String, String>>> o) {
                        o.output(userCollection);
                      }
                    }))
            .apply(
                Window.<Map<String, String>>into(new GlobalWindows())
                    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                    .discardingFiredPanes())
            .apply(View.asSingleton());
```

I'm sure there is an issue with  `o.output(userCollection);`, can you please help me out here.

I'm running into the following issue.

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: com.streaming.pipelines.ContactPipeline$1, @ProcessElement process(Long, Instant, OutputReceiver), @ProcessElement process(Long, Instant, OutputReceiver), parameter of type DoFn.OutputReceiver<PCollection<KV<String, String>>> at index 2: OutputReceiver should be parameterized by java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.streaming.pipelines.ContactPipeline$1, @ProcessElement process(Long, Instant, OutputReceiver), @ProcessElement process(Long, Instant, OutputReceiver), parameter of type DoFn.OutputReceiver<PCollection<KV<String, String>>> at index 2: OutputReceiver should be parameterized by java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures$ErrorReporter.throwIllegalArgument(DoFnSignatures.java:2397)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures$ErrorReporter.checkArgument(DoFnSignatures.java:2403)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures.analyzeExtraParameter(DoFnSignatures.java:1406)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures.analyzeProcessElementMethod(DoFnSignatures.java:1230)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures.parseSignature(DoFnSignatures.java:638)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures.lambda$getSignature$0(DoFnSignatures.java:294)
    at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1127)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignatures.getSignature(DoFnSignatures.java:294)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo.validate(ParDo.java:614)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo.of(ParDo.java:403)
    at com.streaming.pipelines.ContactPipeline.buildPipeline(ContactPipeline.java:61)
    at com.streaming.pipelines.StreamingApp.main(StreamingApp.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    ... 8 more
```

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: Are you getting an error when running above pipelines ?

Comment: Yes @chamikara, I've updated the discussion with the error stack.

Comment: Please let me know how to update side input periodically.